# modified after being freed - returning a C array of `c_str` (const char*) within a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, c, malloc, c-strings

How do I get a c_str array from a `std::vector` (inside a `struct`) for C users to use?

Attempt:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct { size_t size; const char** arr; } CStrStrArray;

CStrStrArray f() {
    const std::vector<const char*> cStrVec {"foo", "bar"}; 
    /* pretend ^this is huge^ with size + contents not known ahead of time */

    const char **cStrArr = (const char**)malloc(cStrVec.size());
    std::copy(cStrVec.begin(), cStrVec.end(), cStrArr);
    /* also tried `cStrVec.data();` */
    return {cStrVec.size(), cStrArr};
}

/* pretend this is 'main.c' and the above is in an `extern C` elsewhere */
int main(void) {
    CStrStrArray c_str_arr = f();
    free(c_str_arr.arr);
    c_str_arr.size = 0;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error:

```
malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7ff996d3d790: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x7ff996d08280
executable(17572,0x11c6d5e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: Hi @AT - you are not copying the contents, you are copying the pointers - and the contents scope finished when the method finished..  Try putting "foo" as say a static const outside the method and see how it differs.

Comment: @MrR It's pointers to string literals so it's okay to copy yhe pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert `std::vector<std::string>>` into `CStrStrArray` you do not need intermediate step and create additional `std::vector<const char *>`:

```
CStrStrArray f( const std::vector<std::string> &v ) {
    CStrStrArray r{ v.size(), 
         reinterpret_cast<const char **>( malloc( sizeof( char * ) * v.size() ) };
    for( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
        r.arr[i] = strdup( v[i].c_str() );
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I can't make it `static` because I don't know the size of it ahead of time…

Comment: You do not have to know its size ahead of time even if it is static, do you mean it will change from call to call?

Comment: @Slava - Yes it's calling an HTTPS API on a remote server, and then I'm filtering down the response into a string vector, and then I'm converting that string vector into a c_str array

Comment: @AT String vector as?

Comment: Well I have a big vector of structs then I convert it into a vector of `std::string` (or `const char*`) then I convert that to a c_str array (`const char**`).

Comment: If it is vector of std::string then you cannot pass it into this structure, that would have the same issue with dangling pointers

Comment: Yeah so I call `strdup` as I iterated through it on the `.c_str` output

Comment: @AT so you iterate over `std::vector<std::string>` and convert it to `std::vector<const char *>` and then convert that to `CStrStrArray`? You can convert `std::vector<std::string>` directly to `CStrStrArray` looks like AB problem

Comment: @At see my updated answer how to convert `std::vector<std::string>>` directly

Comment: Thanks actually I [just now] switched to `char *const*` to get over MSVC issues and switched to your solution. So upvoting + accepted yours.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't allocating sufficient memory. You only allocate memory for 2 bytes but you want memory for 2 char pointers. So change it like:

```
malloc(cStrVec.size()) --> malloc(cStrVec.size() * sizeof *cStrArr)
                                  \------------/   \--------------/
                                   Number of        size of a single
                                   char pointers    char pointer
                                   in the vector

                                  \-------------------------------/
                                          Memory needed
```

Comment: It should be `cStrVec.size() * sizeof(char *)`, you allocate too match

Comment: @Slava `cStrVec.size() * sizeof(char *)` is the same as `cStrVec.size() * sizeof *cStrArr`. However, the last is "the better C coding style" - for several reasons. Likewise: `int d; assert(sizeof d == sizeof(int));` is fine

Comment: The thing that caught me out about this was that I can refer to the variable before it's 'made', like this would not make sense `char c = c + 5`; but I guess `sizeof` is special?

Comment: Yea you are right, I thought that  `cStrArr` is a pointer to `CStrStrArray`

Comment: @AT Yes, `sizeof` is special.

Comment: Interesting. +1

Comment: @AT Maybe this could be interresting for you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195386/why-is-sizeof-called-a-compile-time-operator